# My WP_Query didn't work after upgrading to WordPress 3.2

Tags: wp-query, upgrade, options

I created a custom loop using WP_Query for my featured content slider.

```
<?php
$slider_query = new WP_Query();
$slider_query->query("posts_per_page=5&tag=".(get_option('cgr_slider_tag'))" ");?>
<?php while ($slider_query->have_posts()) : $slider_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article class="slide-item ">

     ....
```

It works fine in previous 3.1.4 , but after upgraded to 3.2 that code is just didn't work. No error found in WP_Debug mode, and Then i try to directly assign the tag name without using the get_option :

```
<?php
$slider_query = new WP_Query();
$slider_query->query("posts_per_page=5&tag=tag1");?>
<?php while ($slider_query->have_posts()) : $slider_query->the_post(); ?>

 <article class="slide-item ">


  ....
```

it works, so i assume the problem is the get_option thing. I've checked the database and other part of the theme that also using get_option and found no problem.

I start thinking that the problem is  I didn't code the get_option part correctly, i'm php noob so maybe it's about encapsed string or others.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
$slider_query->query("posts_per_page=5&tag=".(get_option('cgr_slider_tag'))" ");
```

should be:

```
$slider_query->query("posts_per_page=5&tag=".(get_option('cgr_slider_tag')));
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. I should learn more about writing a good php code.